# How to get half/partial star rating

Tags: jquery, css, rating-system

I've used jquery star rating at a website. I used [this plugin](https://github.com/sabberworm/jStarbox) to do this. At one page, I've to make the star rating read-only mode and now I need star will be shown with half/partial state according to "average" value like this image:

[image]

I saw this feature at that plugin's demo. [This is their demo link](http://sabberworm.github.io/jStarbox/). I though by using `average: 0.42` at jQuery makes the star partial automatically like the demo. But, it didn't do that. I can't find any other option to do this at their documentation. So, **how can I make the star rating image partial according to value**?

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/51LcduLr/)

jQuery:

```
$('.starbox').starbox({
    average: 0.42
});
```

Comment: using 0.42 is the same as saying 2.1 / 5 which is not what they have - you need to make the average 0.48484848484848486 as in the example image to get the same rendering as they have, see answer from @speak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
$('.starbox').starbox({
    average: 0.48,
    changeable: false // turning the rating into read-only mode
});
```

And it gave me partial stars just fine. Adjust the value and it'll go up or down in increments.

Comment: that's all! I thought, there is any other issue. Because, I expected 4.2 won't show the full star state. That's why, I didn't try with other value. So, that plugin don't allow partial state for some partial value?